Insert sql but all rows have the same id (no unique constraint)
I'm trying to make an insert where the first row is the default item and the other rows are the variants with different language (making a primary key with id and locale) and I was thinking on something like this but it's not working:
with data as (
    select uuid_generate_v4() as uuid
)
insert into content (id, type, locale)
select
(uuid, 'page', 'en-us'),
(uuid, 'page', 'es-mx')
from data

I tried using a CTE to get an UUID and then use that for all the inserts for that I need to use SELECT instead of VALUES, I also need to return results.

This UUID nonsense has gotten out of hand. Why create a UUID(Universally unique identifier) that you want to repeat?

You can use a CTE, but a simple subquery does the job. You just can't keep the function uuid_generate_v4() in the SELECT list, or a new UUID is generated for every row.
INSERT INTO content (id, type, locale)
SELECT id, 'page', locale
FROM   uuid_generate_v4() id
    ,  unnest('{en-us, es-mx}'::text[]) locale;


What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?

Or even:
INSERT INTO content (id, type, locale)
SELECT id, 'page', unnest('{en-us, es-mx}'::text[])
FROM   uuid_generate_v4() id;

About set-returning functions in the SELECT list:

What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?

I do wonder about your relational design, that would require to store 'page' redundantly ...

I found this solution but I'm not sure if it can be improved:
with data as (
    select uuid_generate_v4() as uuid
)
insert into content (id, type, locale)
select data.uuid, 'page', 'en-us'
from data
union
select data.uuid, 'page', 'es-mx'
from data

So with this I can add N times of variants for each language using the same uuid.

Use UNION ALL rather than UNION to improve the performance unless you're not sure whether your list of languages contains the same language multiple times and you need to exclude the duplicates. See https://dbfiddle.uk/udas1_rO

@JonasMetzler I can filter duplicates before building the sql, when using UNION ALL lets me append multiple selects from... lets say adding two more languages?

Sure, you can combine many of them. I don't know if there is any limit of maximum UNION ALL queries in PostgreSQL, I never heard someone encountered it. So I can't imagine that would be an issue for you.

342 times a union all does not seem to be a problem (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/bkaHlStm) so plenty of options before hitting the "maybe I should change  my database design... "

You can use unnest() to convert an array to multiple rows, (and string_to_array for splitting a string into an array):
insert into content (id, type, locale) 
select uuid_generate_v4(), 'page', unnest(string_to_array('en-us,es-mx',','))


OP was trying to use the same UUID for all rows ("...to get an UUID and then use that for all the inserts..."). This is creating different uuid's.
